# how to get single string from qstringlist

Tags: c++, qt

I am building an image viewer application. I store all image path into qSringlist. Now I need to get one image path every time. How can i do this ?

Here is my code

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_Next_clicked()
{

//initial value
int count = 0;

do {
    //show image into label
    QImage img(fileName.at(count));
    ui->lbl_Image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    qDebug() << fileName.at(count);
    count++;
    return;
    } while (count < fileName.size());

}
```

Comment: can you paste an example of how your `QStringList`. i can't see where and how you put them into the `QStringList`

Comment: You should check if your QStringList is not empty before using it to initialize QImage - in this case loop will run even if fileName.size() is zero.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_btn_Open_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "open()";
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,
                                                    tr("Open File"), QDir::currentPath());
    if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < fileName.size(); i++){
            QImage image(fileName.at(i));
            ui->lbl_Image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        }
    }
}

Comment: copied&pasted&highlighted: http://pastebin.com/X5cFAfaS

Answer (score 1):

initialize `count` outside your `on_btn_Next_clicked()` method and then every time the method is called increment the counter, when the counter is the same size of the `QStringList` reset it back to 0

```
// initialize count outside the method
int count = 0;


void MainWindow::on_btn_Next_clicked()
{
    if(count <= filename.size()) {

        //show image into label
        QImage img(fileName.at(count));
        ui->lbl_Image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        qDebug() << fileName.at(count);
        this->count++;
        return;
        } else {
            //reset the counter back to 0
            this->count = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the filename:

```
 const QStringList fileNames = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, tr("Open File"), QDir::currentPath());
```

Use a foreach loop to iterate:

```
  foreach(const QString& image, fileNames){
    ui->lbl_Image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(image)));
    qDebug() << "Get this filename: " << image;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are correct on how to get a specific item from the list, even the question's code does that correctly.

However all fail to mention that this will always show the last image in the list, since the UI never gets a chance to display any of the others.

The loop is never returning to the event loop, thus never allowing the application to process the label's update() request.